# Pyspark,SQL, python

Tags: python, sql, dataframe, pyspark

```
df = spark.sql("select count(*) from zys")
df.display() # value is getting as DataFrame.
```

I need to convert from `df` to a single value..so that I can insert the value in a SQL table

I have tried `df[0]`, but it didn't work.

Comment: You can load the table as a DataFrame, then use `.count()` to get the total count of the records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a Spark DataFrame `df` containing a single value to a scalar value, you can use the `first()` function. Here's an example:

```py
result = df.first()[0]
```

In the above code, `first()` retrieves the first row of the DataFrame as a Row object, and `[0]` accesses the first element of that row, which corresponds to the count value in this case. The resulting value can be stored in a variable, `result`, for further processing.